# htmlからjsの呼び出し

Tags: javascript, monaca, html5

Monacaのサンプルのメモ帳アプリにあるjsのlocalstrageを応用してアプリを作っています。

そこでそのサンプルがhtmlからjsを呼び出しているのですが、`<script src=""></scropt>`のようなパターンでなくどう呼び出しているのかわかりません。

html

```
<!-- Add Memo Page -->
<div data-role="page" id="AddPage">
    <header data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="c">
        <a data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-icon="back">Back</a>
        <h1>Add Memo</h1>
    </header>
    <section data-role="content">
        <label for="Memo">Memo:</label>
        <textarea id="Memo"></textarea>
        <a data-role="button" data-icon="check" id="SaveBtn">Save</a>
    </section>
</div>
```

js

```
///// Save memo
function saveMemoList(list) {
    try {
        localStorage.setItem("memo_list", JSON.stringify(list));
    } catch (e) {
        alert('Error saving to storage.');
        throw e;
    }
}
```

一応サンプルページのurlもつけます（見当違いな所を見ている可能性もあります）
（https://docs.monaca.io/ja/sampleapp/samples/memo_application/）

Comment: 参考： この質問は [「jsの外部ファイルをhtmlで読み込む」](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/32270/js%E3%81%AE%E5%A4%96%E9%83%A8%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%82%92html%E3%81%A7%E8%AA%AD%E3%81%BF%E8%BE%BC%E3%82%80) に続きます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<script>`タグで読み込んでいます。

サンプルページでの記述は、分かりやすいようにHTMLとJavascriptの大まかな部分を抜粋しているだけで、サンプルファイル全体をダウンロードしてコード全てを見ると、`index.html`の一番下で

```
   :
<script src="components/loader.js"></script>
<script src="js/memo.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/cssua.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

と、`<script>`タグを使用してJavascriptファイルを読みこんでいるのが分かります。

Comment: 読み込みは下でしたか！気づきませんでしたありがとうございます！   どこで何を行うのかの指示はできないのですか？    例えばここでsaveMemoListを使いたいとき、id指定だとかC言語の様に関数名(int,int)みたいにするのでしょうか？ (始めたばかりで全然わからなくて)

Comment: HTML+Javascriptでは、HTMLを読み込んでからJavascriptを読み込むことで、とりあえずまずページを表示し、見かけの遅延時間を短くするというテクニックがあります。一番下にあるのはおそらくそういうことでしょう。

Comment: それ以外の質問の件ですが、質問の状況が分かりにくくちょっとコメントでは答えにくそうなので、再度質問として投稿していただけませんでしょうか？　その際、類似の質問がないか少し検索していただければと思います。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ありがとうございました 再度調べ直して わからなければ 別の質問として質問しようと思います!

Comment: もしこの回答で満足頂けたのでしたら、回答の左の方にある緑の旗を押して回答を承認していただければと思います（義務ではありません）。詳しくは [「自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか?」](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) をご覧ください。