# jsの外部ファイルをhtmlで読み込む

Tags: monaca, jquery-mobile

js初心者です。

monacaのサンプルのメモ帳アプリを応用して　アプリを作っています（課題です）

そこで、htmlの方は大体出来ているのですが　jsの関数をhtmlからどう動かしているのかがわかりませんがbodyの最下部においてあるので、最後にmemo.jsを読み込んで上から処理しているのだと思うのですが、ボタンを押した時にどの関数を読み込むと言った動きがわかりません。

```
    <section data-role="content">
        <label for="Memo">Memo:</label>
        <textarea id="Memo"></textarea>
        <a data-role="button" data-icon="check" id="SaveBtn">Save</a>
    </section>
```

の `<a data-role="button" data-icon="check" id="SaveBtn">Save</a>`　を押したらsaveMemoList(list)関数が呼び出される。　と言った動きです。

↓サンプルアプリ
https://docs.monaca.io/ja/sampleapp/samples/memo_application/

Comment: 参考： この質問はおそらく [「htmlからjsの呼び出し」](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/32261/html%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89js%E3%81%AE%E5%91%BC%E3%81%B3%E5%87%BA%E3%81%97) からの続きです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

サンプルアプリのapp.jsにある以下のコードがクリックされた時に処理を呼び出す設定に該当します。

```
///// Called when app launch
function onReady() {
    initTopPage();
    $("#SaveBtn").click(onSaveBtn);
    $("#TopListView").on("click", "a.show", onShowLink);
    $("#TopListView").on("click", "a.delete", onDeleteLink);
}
```

`$("#SaveBtn")`
idにSaveBtnと設定してある要素の特定

`.click(onSaveBtn)`
クリックイベントの時に呼び出すonSaveBtnを指定

Comment: app.jsの方でしたか！ありがとうございます！色々調べてみます！